# $A: U\to L(\mathbb{R}^m, \mathbb{R^n})$ prove $A: U\to L(\mathbb{R}^m, \mathbb{R^n})$ $\iff$ $A$ is 'exact'

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

> Let $U\subset \mathbb{R^m}$ open and $A: U\to L(\mathbb{R}^m,
>  \mathbb{R^n})$. For all path $\lambda:[a,b]\to U$ of class $C^1$, define
>   the integral of $A$ along the path $\lambda$ as the vector of
>   $\mathbb{R^n}$ given by $\int_{\lambda}A = \int_a^b
>  A(\lambda(t))\lambda'(t) \ dt$. Extend this definition for sectionally
>   $C^1$ paths. Let $(a_{ij}(x))$ be the matrix of $A(x)$ is the
>   canonical basis of $\mathbb{R^m}$ and $\mathbb{R^n}$. Prove that
>   $\int_{\lambda} = 0$ for all closed path $\lambda$ in $U$ if, and only
>   if, there are $n$ functions $f_1, \cdots, f_n$ of class $C^1$ such
>   that $a_{ij} = \frac{\partial f_i}{\partial x_j}$

My guess is that the definition for a sectionally $C^1$ path $\lambda$ will be:

$$\int_{\lambda}A =\sum_i^n\int_{\lambda_i}A$$

for each of the $C^1$ parts $\lambda_i$ of the path $\lambda$. My book presents a theorem that says that:

> Let $w: U\to(\mathbb{R})^*$ be a continuous $1$-form in the open $U\subset \mathbb{R}^n$. The following are equivalent:
>
> $w$ is exact in $U$. 
>   For every closed path $\lambda: [a,b]\to U$, sectionally $C^1$, we have $\int_\lambda w = 0$

This is almost what I need, excpt that $A$ is not a $1$-form. I've ben thinking but couldn't adapt this theorem for a transformation $A$

Comment: $(\int_\gamma A(x)dx)_i = \int_\gamma a_i(x) dx = \int_\gamma \sum_{j=1}^m a_{ij}(x) dx_j$. What happens if you take $\gamma$ to be parallel to the $x_j$ axis ?

Comment: And what makes you think it is not a $1$-form ? Also your quote isn't a theorem but the definition of exact $1$-forms.

Comment: Could you write it better so I can give you a bounty?

Comment: Nope. Write it yourself if you'd like to.